# ITextRenderer not printing Greek characters in pdf

Tags: java, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to convert .xls files to .pdf files. The pdf file is generated but it doesn't print the letters. All the characters of the xls are greek letters and numbers. I changed fonts like million times but nothing happened. Here is my code so far. Any suggestion what could i do?

```
package copyfiles;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.converter.ExcelToHtmlConverter;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
//import java.util.Locale;

public class ConverterXlsx_Pdf {
    //private static final java.util.Locale locale = new Locale( "el", "GR" );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\xlsx_files\\inputXlsFile.xls");

        Document doc = ExcelToHtmlConverter.process(file);

        writePdf(doc);           
    }



    public static void writePdf(Document doc) throws Exception {
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\xlsx_files\\new_file.pdf")) {
            
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            //File fonts =new File("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\arial.ttf");
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\arial.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\arialbd.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\arialbi.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\ariali.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\ARIALN.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\ARIALNB.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\ARIALNBI.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\ARIALNI.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Users\\me\\fonts\\ariblk.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            
            renderer.setDocument(doc,null);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(out);
            out.flush();
        }
    }  
}
```

that is an example of the output file. It only prints the numbers
[image]

Comment: What's there *instead*?

Comment: @KJ i tried with "embedded" but nothing changed

Comment: @g00se you mean instead of greek characters? it prints only the numbers and the symbols but when there's a character it doesn't print anything.. but i tried to create an html file instead of pdf and it created without problems. So I suppose  it is something wrong with pdf creation only

Comment: The problem could be in `ExcelToHtmlConverter.process` You'd better post that too